# CallSite MethodName allways renders as MoveNext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, nlog

When logging using the `CallSite` renderer, the result is always `MoveNext` for the method name. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

NLog version: 4.6.0

Platform:  .NET Core 2

Current NLog config (xml or C#, if relevant)

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-trace" fileName="logs\${machinename}-trace.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${aspnet-request-ip}|${aspnet-User-Identity}|${pad:padding=-5:${uppercase:${level}}}|${assembly-version}|${pad:padding=-3:${threadid}}|${aspnet-mvc-controller}|${callsite:className=True:includeNamespace=False:fileName=False:includeSourcePath=False:methodName=True}|${message}|${exception}"
        maxArchiveFiles="14"
        archiveFileName="logs\archive\${machinename}-trace.{#}.zip"
        archiveNumbering="Date"
        archiveEvery="Saturday"
        archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMdd"
        enableArchiveFileCompression ="true"
        />
```

initialization:

```
    public class Program
{
    private static readonly Logger Logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            Logger.Info("init main");

            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //NLog: catch setup errors
            Logger.Error(e, "Stopped program because of exception");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
            NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
        } 

    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
            })
            .UseNLog() // NLog: setup NLog for Dependency injection
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(ConfigConfiguration);
```

...

What is the current result?

```
2018-08-12 16:44:58.8795|::1||TRACE|8.8.11.0|4  |Home|HomeController.MoveNext|
```

|
What is the expected result?

```
2018-08-12 16:44:58.8795|::1||TRACE|8.8.11.0|4  |Home|HomeController.Index||
```

Did you checked the Internal log? no warning

Please post full exception details (message, stacktrace, inner exceptions: none

Are there any workarounds? no

Is there a version in which it did work? not sure

Can you help us by writing an unit test? no

Comment: Is the method you're looking at `async`? If so, most of the body gets moved/transformed into a different class and I believe the method it ends up in is called `MoveNext`. So follow up is are you using an up to date version of nlog?

Comment: There is no NLog 4.6 (lastest version is currently 4.5.8). Is that the version of NLog.Web.AspNetCore?

Comment: Yes, it is Nlog.Web.AspNetCore 4.6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the Wiki-page for the `${callsite}` layout-renderer:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Callsite-layout-renderer

Try to enable these options:

- cleanNamesOfAnonymousDelegates
- cleanNamesOfAsyncContinuations

Ex.

```
${callsite:className=True:includeNamespace=False:fileName=False:includeSourcePath=False:methodName=True:cleanNamesOfAnonymousDelegates=True:cleanNamesOfAsyncContinuations=True}
```

There is a pending task for NLog ver. 5.0 to have these enabled by default: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1798 (Minor breaking change)

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Sorry I had read that wiki, but no idea why/if I should set these.

Comment: You can consider storing the very wordy callsite-specification in a NLog-Config-Variable , and then just reference in the layouts where needed. Ex could be called `${callsiteasync}`.